# Django: How do I perform a CreateView redirect properly?

Tags: python, django

To perform a redirect I do `return redirect([...])`. However, that only works, if I additionally do `def get_success_url(self):`. The url in it actually doesn't matter, as it is using the redirect of my `def form_valid(self, form):`. Do you know how to avoid the `get_success_url`?

I also tested to just move the return from `form_valid` to `get_success_url`. But then I receive an error that return is missing.

```
class AdminRewardCreate(AdminPermissionRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, FormValidationMixin, AdminBaseRewardView, CreateView):
    form_class = RewardForm
    template_name = 'rewards/admin/create.html'
    success_message = _("Reward has been successfully created.")

    def form_valid(self, form):
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.event = self.request.event
        # when the super method is called the instance
        # is saved because it's a model form
        super().form_valid(form)
        return redirect(
            'rewards:admin:index',
            self.request.organizer.slug,
            self.request.event.slug
        )

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse(
            'rewards:admin:index',
            kwargs={
                'organizer': self.request.organizer.slug,
                'event': self.request.event.slug,
            }
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to call redirect from `form_valid` method. Just need to **return** the super call from function. So I think you can update the `form_valid` like this:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    instance = form.save(commit=False)
    instance.event = self.request.event
    return super().form_valid(form)  # you need to return the super call

def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse(
        'rewards:admin:index',
        kwargs={
            'organizer': self.request.organizer.slug,
            'event': self.request.event.slug,
        }
    )
```

It should fix the problem, also please keep the `get_success_url` implementation in override, because it is going to redirect to that success url.